# synonom for inject or insert into

Tags: synonyms

I want to insert the content of the JSON file into the database.

which word synonm can I use for the **inject** or **insert into** in this case?

> The content of the JSON file are injected into the database at the server side.

Comment: I can say, at this moment, "import"

Comment: You can just simple use *move* as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with import like what @Cardinal suggested, "save" or "store" would also work.

Comment: import into or to the database?

Comment: yeah, why not, come to think of it though I'd probably use save to database

Comment: oh, sorry, import into the database, or save to the database

Answer (score 1):

You would be adding the json to the database. Adding to the database is just a hair less formal than to say insert into the database, but it means precisely the same thing. I'd only use the word insert if describing the technical process in documentation.

What you do not want to use are the words inject or injection, if you're referring to a normal database addition or update. Using the terms inject or injection not just with databases, but with programming in general, implies something hackish is going on.

Take for example [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) or [HTTP Header Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_header_injection). These are both titles of serious exploits. Years ago, a method of iPhone jailbreaking involved code **injection** through a pdf exploit. Basically any time you hear injection in development circles, something bad is happening.